# exporting list of variables in docker run

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

We have a set of variables in env file as given below

examples.env

```
A="/path1"
B="/path2":$A
```

Now, docker run cannot substitute $B for `/path/path1`, due to its limitations

So, I want to export the variable in launcher script and then call those variable using -e flag, as given below

mydocker.sh

```
input="examples.env"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  export $line
done < "$input"

docker run --rm -e <Some code> centos8
```

Now how to create docker command to get all the variables?

Following docker command works
`docker run --rm -e A -e B centos8`
But If the number of variables in examples.env file is unknown, then how can we generate docker run command?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what these variables are?  Can you set them from somewhere like an entrypoint script?  Or, if they're filesystem paths, can you just make them non-configurable properties of the image (data files are _always_ in `/data`, full stop)?

Comment: The variables are collection of different project variables, so they differ everytime. Lets just say A, B, C, D. There are some dependencies among them.like A is basic, B and C have $A in its definition. We cannot set them from entrypoint as the docker image is separate from project image.

Comment: I'd look first at simplifying the problem; you might be able to conditionally set the derived variables in an entrypoint script, fix some of the filesystem paths, or just outright delete some of these settings.  If you really need to dynamically construct the list of environment variables a scripting language like Python might be more appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks for replying David, yes Python can be a good substitution, but currently the script is such a big and complicated that it will be nightmare to convert it to python. The entrypoint is out of question, as they are in two different domain of project and cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source the variables file in your `mydocker.sh` script insted of `export` and concat each variable with `--env`, at the and eval the concatenated string to variable so the variables will interpreted.

Here is an example:

```
# Source the variables file so they will be available in current script.
. ./examples.env
# Define docker env string it will lokk like below:.
# --env A=/path1 --env B=/path1/path2
dockerenv=""
input="examples.env"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    dockerenv="${dockerenv} --env $line"
done < "$input"
# Evaluate the env string so the variables in it will be interpreted
dockerenv=$(eval echo $dockerenv)

docker run --rm $dockerenv centos8
```

P.S. 
You need the `--env` insted of `-e` becouse `-e` will be interpreted as `echo` command argument.